# Need local security rights on Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, windows-8, security

A program I am trying to install (Hazus 2.0) requires the following:

"Confirm that the user account that is running the setup (in addition to having admin rights) has the following Local Security Policy rights. Check with your Network Administrator on how to verity/access the Local Security Policy interface"

The local security rights referred to here are "Debug Programs" and "Manage Auditing and Security Log".

I own a Windows 8.1. Not Windows 8 pro, just plain Windows 8.1. When I type secpol.msc it does not show. How can I edit the registry to activate these rights?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is two ways:

Easy - is to find machine that runs Pro or Enterprise version and remotely edit settings on target computer.

Second choice is to mess up directly with registry.
Download from Microsoft excel file that referencing all security settings that changed with front-end such as `secpol.msc`

The excel file you can find on Micosoft site:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=25250